# Script that counts quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, change-making-problem

I am learning Python and I wrote a script that counts how many coins you would need for an amount in dollars. I was wondering if I could make any improvements to it.

```
def change():
    amnt = float(input("Enter an amount in USD: "))
    quarters = divmod(amnt, 0.25)
    print("Quarters: ", quarters[0])
    amnt = round(quarters[1], 2)
    dimes = divmod(amnt, 0.10)
    print("Dimes: ", dimes[0])
    amnt = round(dimes[1], 2)
    nickels = divmod(amnt, 0.
    print("Nickels: ", nickels[0])
    amnt = round(nickels[1], 2)
    penny = divmod(amnt, 0.01)
    print("Pennies", penny[0])
change()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Separate input from processing.  If you want to test your method with a number of different values, you'll have to call `change()` multiple times, and enter in the value each time.  Instead, change the function to accept the `amnt`, and you can call it many times passing in the amount of cash as an argument:

```
def change(amnt):
    # ...
```

Working with tuples from `divmod` is awkward.  Python has deconstructing assignment, which will take a returned `tuple` an assign the members to separate variables:

```
def change(amnt):
    quarters, amnt = divmod(amnt, 0.25)
    print("Quarters: ", quarters)

    dimes, amnt = divmod(round(amnt, 2), 0.10)
    print("Dimes: ", dimes)
```

For the last operation, you don't use the remainder, so the "throw-away" variable `_` can be used for it:

```
    pennies, _ = divmod(round(amnt, 2), 0.01)
    print("Pennies: ", pennies)
```

If you import this script into another program, you probably don't want the script to immediately run; rather you just want the `change(amnt)` function to be defined so this other program can call it.  This is done by adding a "guard" at the end of the script, which only runs the code if the script is invoked directly:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    amnt = float(input("Enter an amount in USD: "))
    change(amnt)
```

---

In addition to separating input from processing, you might want to separate the processing from the output:

```
def change(amnt):
    quarters, amnt = divmod(amnt, 0.25)
    dimes,    amnt = divmod(amnt, 0.10)
    nickels,  amnt = divmod(amnt, 0.05)
    pennies = round(amnt / 0.01, 0)

    return list(map(int, [quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    amnt = float(input("Enter an amount in USD: "))
    quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies = change(amnt)
    print("{} quarters, {} dimes, {} nickels, {} pennies".format(
          quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies))
```

---

Despite attempts to fix rounding errors with things like `round(amnt,2)`, calling `change(0.85)` returns `[3, 0, 1, 5]`, showing that there wasn't quite enough change to make 2 nickels, but after removing 1 nickel, approximately 5 pennies remained.  This is caused by floating point math.

We can avoid these issues by switching to integer math, based on the number of pennies:

```
def change(amnt):
    pennies = round(amnt * 100)   # Convert from dollars to pennies

    quarters, pennies = divmod(pennies, 25)
    dimes,    pennies = divmod(pennies, 10)
    nickels,  pennies = divmod(pennies, 5)

    return quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies

if __name__ == '__main__':
    amnt = float(input("Enter an amount in USD: "))
    quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies = change(amnt)
    print("{} quarters, {} dimes, {} nickels, {} pennies".format(
          quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies))
```

As mentioned in the comments by @Ilmari, `round(...)` with only a single argument will round the value to the nearest whole number and return an **integer** value.  When integer values are used with `divmod`, results are also integers, so switching from dollars-and-cents to integer pennies eliminates the ugly rounding issues.

Comment: +1 for everything except your non-PEP8 formatting, even though it does look nice here.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the behavior of single-argument `round()` autoconverting floats to ints is specific to Python 3. In Python 2, you'd need to explicitly write `pennies = int(round(amnt * 100))` if you want the results to be ints. (Of course, using an explicit `int()` here is OK in Python 3 too, just redundant.)